# Multiple Dynamic MVC 5 Radio Button Group Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to validate multiple radio button groups on a razor page.  The radio buttons are dynamically generated through an editor template.  When they are displayed on the page, they show up as buttons with glyphicons.  Right now I have 19 different radio button groups in this form.  When I click submit, it shows 3 validation messages on each radio button group if one of the buttons is not selected as well as displays that in the validation summary at the top as well.  Ideally I would like it if I could have a red border around the button group if the user submits the form and does not select an option in that group as well as some text below the group that says they need to select an option.  How can I accomplish this through jquery or razor code or both?

Editor Template

```
@Html.ValidationSummary()
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Proposals[d].lVoteOptions)
    @for (int v = 0; v < Model.Proposals[d].lVoteOptions.Count; v++)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Proposals[d].lVoteOptions[v].Icon)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Proposals[d].lVoteOptions[v].Title)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Proposals[d].lVoteOptions[v].Option_ID)
        <label class="btn btn-default btn-radio-group">
            <span class="glyphicon @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Proposals[d].lVoteOptions[v].Icon)"></span>
            @Html.DisplayFor(m => Model.Proposals[d].lVoteOptions[v].Title)
            @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => Model.Proposals[d].SelectedVoteOption, true, Model.Proposals[d].lVoteOptions[v].Option_ID, new { id = Model.Proposals[d].lVoteOptions[v].Option_ID })                                                            
        </label>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model.Proposals[d].SelectedVoteOption)
    }
</div>
```

ViewModel

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Proposal must be selected")]
public int SelectedVoteOption { get; set; }
```

jquery to block modal popup on form submit if form is not valid

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnBallotFormSubmit").click(function () {
        var ValidStatus = $("#ballotForm").valid();
        console.log(ValidStatus);
    if (ValidStatus == false) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

index cshtml page

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "ballotForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.BallotViewModel, new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo { HtmlFieldPrefix = "BallotViewModel" } })
    <table class="col-sm-12">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="submit" id="btnBallotFormSubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-md btn-submit" data-target="#modal-container" data-toggle="modal">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send" aria-hidden="true"></span> Submit
                </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

BallotViewModel

```
public class BallotViewModel
    {
        public bool IsVoteConfirmationView { get; set; }
        public List<ProposalViewModel> Proposals { get; set; }
    }
```

ProposalViewModel

```
public class ProposalViewModel
{
    public string ProposalItemID { get; set; }
    public string ProposalItemTitle { get; set; }
    public string DirectorImageURL { get; set; }
    public string BookmarkLink { get; set; }
    public string ArtifactBookmarkLink { get; set; }
    public string ArtifactsLink { get { return AppSettings.MeetingArtifactLocation; } }
    public int Option0_ID { get; set; }
    public string Option0_Name { get; set; }
    public int Option1_ID { get; set; }
    public string Option1_Name { get; set; }
    public int Option2_ID { get; set; }
    public string Option2_Name { get; set; }
    public int Option3_ID { get; set; }
    public string Option3_Name { get; set; }

    public int MgmtRecommendation { get; set; }
    public bool IsHeader { get; set; }
    public int TagOrder { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Proposal must be selected")]
    public int SelectedVoteOption { get; set; }

    public bool IsVoteConfirmationView { get; set; }

    public bool DirectorProposal { get; set; }


    public List<VoteOptionViewModel> lVoteOptions { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your not using an `EditorTemplate` - you are using a partial and writing twice as much code as necessary to try and make it work like an `EditorTemplate` You also do not need to check`.valid()` since the form will not submit if you have done this correctly. You need to show more of you model(s) in order to solve this.

Comment: Correct the form won't submit, but I still have to check if the form is valid or else the modal popup screen overlay will kick in.  There is a lot of code as part of this prototype I'm working on, too much to copy and paste in here. What exactly do you need to see that will help you understand what I am trying to accomplish?

Comment: Start with the models - the one defined by property `BallotViewModel` and also include what you use for `@model ???` in the partial and what you have names that partial

Comment: You also appear to be missing the `@for (int d = 0; ...)` loop in the partial (which wont actually be required anyway if you do use an `EditorTemplate` correctly

Comment: The for loop is there but that partial is very big.  There is alot going on in there and I have to do multiple for loops unfortunately to get the data to display the right way.

Comment: No, you do not need (and should not have) any loops if you use an `EditorTemplate` correctly (the only loop you need is for generating the radio button group). Your current partial is generating multiple `@Html.ValidationSummary()` which will be a problem. As far as having a border around the whole radio button group, that will not happen by default and you will need to write you own script to handle that.

Comment: Based on your model, you need a file named `ProposalViewModel.cshtml` in `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` with `@model ProposalViewModel` and then in the main view its just `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Proposals)` assuming the main view is `@model BallotViewModel`. But `@Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Proposals[d].lVoteOptions)` will be a problem because `lVoteOptions` is a collections (look at the html it generates to understand why this will never bind to your model)

Comment: The core data comes from one single data table.  From there I split the data up into individual viewmodels to get the radio button groups to be named properly.  From the HomeController I get the core data and parse it out to ProposalViewModel.  I then look for the rows that have vote options in them and split that out to the voteoptions viewmodel.  Some rows are headers, some are not so I separate it out.  All of that sits under the BallotViewModel umbrella.  Maybe I'm trying to cram to much into one single partial view, I'm not sure.

Comment: So you could have one row consist of a title with 3 columns of vote options, and the next row could be a header row with just column headers and then the next row could have a title with 2 columns of vote options.  Its not very consistent so I had to make it flexible enough for the core dataset.